# Combine delegates and bindings as data source, highlight a index

Tags: macos, core-plot

I am trying to achive a mouseover overlay on a scatter plot, like this:

[image]

Have implemented a NSTrackingArea, mouseEvents and `indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint` and I know the closest index.

I would like to high-light a certain plot-index and found this (looked in the Mac app examples in CPTTest):

```
symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

The problem is that I am using bindings and not the delegate as data source. I have not managed to combine bindings and delegates as far as I can see? symbolForScatterPlot is never called if I don't set the datasoruce. If I set the datasource the bindings does not work.

(Or is there a better way of doing this?)

I appreciate any feedback or hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a binding to an array of plot symbols using the binding identifier `CPTScatterPlotBindingPlotSymbols`. This array should be the same size as your data arrays. If you don't want a symbol at a particular index, insert `[NSNull null]` in the array instead of a plot symbol.

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thank you again Eric! I will investigate this further.